# Access HttpContextBase object from static class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-state

ASP.NET 4.6.1 using MVC 5.

I have a class with the following constructor and I'm setting a session variable:

```
public class MyClass()
{
    private HttpContextBase Context { get; set; }

    public MyClass(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public bool CheckForAccess()
    {
        Context.Session["MyVariable"] = "Hello";
        return true;
    }
}
```

I can access the session and pass it to my object from my controller like so:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var myclass= new MyClass(HttpContext);
    var excluded = myclass.CheckForAccess();
}
```

This is working fine. Now i have a static class and i need to call the same function in MyClass:

```
public static class MyClassExtension
{
    public static bool Check()
    {
   //here's where i'm stuck
    var myclass = new MyClass(I_need_to_pass_the_HttpContextBase_from_here);
        return myclass.CheckForAccess();
    }
}
```

This is where i'm stuck. I'm clearly trying to access the current session of the logged in user and pass it around when i have to. What do i pass from my static class to the constructor of with an HttpContextBase parameter so it can be used in the MyClass object? Thanks

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I do not know what to send in my static class to the constructor when I instantiate the non static object. The comment //heres the problem is where im stuck

Comment: Add the context as a parameter to your static function and pass that in...

Comment: from your page, you can call MyCallExtension.Check(HttpContext) and your code should work!! not sure where you are really struck

Comment: Thats not what i'm doing..I'm making the call to my non static method from my static class. I need to access the HttpContextBase from my static class and pass it to my non static class.

Comment: @JeffMercado - thats what im trying to do. Show me how in code

Comment: @BoundForGlory - Are you asking to access HttpContextBase directly without being that parameter passed to your static method? I'm sure that's not the way you should look into.  I'm actually not sure what you are trying to do but it looks like your logic needs a second-thought

Comment: @techspider - check out the answer. you were making this to be something it wasnt

Comment: @BoundForGlory, I would not prefer that solution; you can also see Brian's suggestions; there are always two things - getting things done and getting things done in the right way :)

Comment: @techspider - i agree with you 100%. I have checks for error in my application. You are seeing a very small part of my entire app. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current`, but beware: if the static is called outside of the ASP.NET request, `HttpContext.Current` will be null (or may be null in certain situations depending on how you are using this):

```
public static bool Check()
{
    var myclass = new MyClass(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
    return myclass.CheckForAccess();
}
```

HttpCOntextWrapper exists to wrap the old HttpContext sealed class and support the HttpContextBase base class.